# Can not create a temporary file

Tags: java, temporary-files

I am using this piece of code to create a temporary file:

```
String tmpDirectoryOp = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
File tmpDirectory = new File(tmpDirectoryOp);
File fstream = File.createTempFile("tmpDirectory",".flv", tmpDirectory);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fstream);
DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fos);

dos.writeChars("Write something");

fstream.deleteOnExit();

fos.close();
dos.close();
```

But there is no `tmpDirectory.flv` in my project folder. The write sentence is in a loop, which takes quite long time to finish, so the problem is not that the file is deleted before I could see it.
Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: It will not appear in your "project folder", but in your system temporary folder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Creates an empty file in the **default
>   temporary-file directory**, using the
>   given prefix and suffix to generate
>   its name. Invoking this method is
>   equivalent to invoking
>   createTempFile(prefix, suffix, null).

You can get temp dir for your operating system using

```
System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

You have executed `deleteOnExit()`

> **public void deleteOnExit()**
>   Requests that the file or directory
>   denoted by this abstract pathname be
>   deleted when the virtual machine
>   terminates. Deletion will be attempted
>   only for normal termination of the
>   virtual machine, as defined by the
>   Java Language Specification. Once
>   deletion has been requested, it is not
>   possible to cancel the request. This
>   method should therefore be used with
>   care.
>
> Note: this method should not be used
>   for file-locking, as the resulting
>   protocol cannot be made to work
>   reliably. The FileLock facility should
>   be used instead.

- [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

Comment: with your advice, sould I have a tmpDirectory.flv in my tmp directory?? I don't have it

Comment: @mujer esponja Updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

!! Please close the streams !!

```
File fstream = File.createTempFile("tmpDirectory",".flv"); 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fstream); 
DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(fos); 

dos.writeChars("Write something"); 

fstream.deleteOnExit();
```

**

```
fos.close();
dos.close();
```

**

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked in your `/tmp` folder?

If you want to create a temporary file in a specified folder, you need the [3 param `createTempFile` function](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try to flush and close the stream.